# What's the more efficient XML Structure for data parsing ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

I have two versions of XML File to be parsed for an iOS app that renders a graph with the XML Data.

Structure#1 :

```
<graphData>
<headerBundle>
    <chartTitle>Rainfall History</chartTitle>
    <xTitle>No. of cms</xTitle>
    <yTitle></yTitle>
    <nLegends>6</nLegends>
    <legendBundle>
        <legend>Jan</legend>
        <legend>Feb</legend>
        <legend>Mar</legend>
        <legend>Apr</legend>
        <legend>May</legend>
        <legend>Jun</legend>
    </legendBundle>
</headerBundle>
<dataBundle>
    <data>City A,1,2,4,7,8,4</data>
    <data>City B,4,7,8,4,2,8</data>
    <data>City C,8,4,4,7,9,6</data>
</dataBundle>
```

Structure#2 :

```
<graphData>
<headerBundle>
    <chartTitle>Rainfall History</chartTitle>
    <xTitle>No. of cms</xTitle>
    <yTitle></yTitle>
    <nLegends>6</nLegends>
    <legendBundle>
        <legend>Jan</legend>
        <legend>Feb</legend>
        <legend>Mar</legend>
        <legend>Apr</legend>
        <legend>Jun</legend>
        <legend>Jul</legend>
    </legendBundle>
</headerBundle>
<dataBundle>
    <dataPacket>
        <xLabel>City A</xLabel>
            <Jan>1</Jan>
            <Feb>2</Feb>
            <Mar>4</Mar>
            <Apr>7</Apr>
            <May>8</May>
            <Jun>4</Jun>
    </dataPacket>       
    <dataPacket>
        <xLabel>City B</xLabel>
            <Jan>4</Jan>
            <Feb>7</Feb>
            <Mar>8</Mar>
            <Apr>4</Apr>
            <May>2</May>
            <Jun>8</Jun>
    </dataPacket>       
    <dataPacket>
        <xLabel>City C</xLabel>
            <Jan>8</Jan>
            <Feb>4</Feb>
            <Mar>4</Mar>
            <Apr>7</Apr>
            <May>9</May>
            <Jun>6</Jun>
    </dataPacket>       
</dataBundle>
```

In terms of File Size, Data Cost and Reusability, Structure#1 scores.

But that would involve a lot of processing time in String Splitting.
So, on the whole, what would be the optimal of the two ?

Answer (score 0):

With option 1 you can split the string with `componentsSeparatedByString:`. You should test to find out which is faster. You also probably shouldn't worry about it until you have some reason to (don't optimise early, this probably won't be what makes your app slow).

Comment: Thanks Wain ! 
It is just that, while trying to write a Web-Service, it would be far more easier if I choose the first option. It could be reused for multiple types of graphs.
The latter on the other hand demands a new Class definition for each kind of graph.